# How do I deal with font scaling set on os-level (e.g. scale all fonts to 150%)?

Tags: html, css

Some Operating Systems allow the user to specify that all fonts should be scaled by a certain amount. When a page is designed for specific font sizes, that breaks everything.
Is there a proper way to deal with this?

NOTE:
This is not for a regular web site, it's a mobile webview, used by an app. One page displays vouchers, and they have a fixed size, so the font must have a fixed size aswell.

Comment: You should build your page to being able to handle this I think. I am not sure if there are any ways of 'dealing with this'. Those people scale their font's because they cannot read properly without it (mostly). So if you'd deal with it somehow they will have trouble using your website.

Comment: so rem/em will for some reason prevent scaling?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent that. You should allow the font sizing anyway for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Read this article: https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/

Answer (score 0):

You should use responsive design with `em` units in the media queries.

See [this page](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/live/xmgJXZ): Watch it at 1000px window width and then zoom the browser font size: you will see that the number of columns decreases as the font size increases.

[Here is the full codepen](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/xmgJXZ)